# Extracting data.frame from simple features object in R

Tags: r, sf

Is there an sf-native (i.e. "correct") way of extracting everything except the geometry column from a simple features object? This works

```
df <- dplyr::select(as.data.frame(sf), -geometry)
```

but the `select( , -geometry)` step feels unnecessary. Also, it doesn't remove the geometry attributes.

Comment: Also possible with `df <- st_drop_geometry(df)`

Comment: @radek Also in the CRAN version?

Comment: I velieve so. Currently `0.7-2` on cran. And it's here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.7-2/topics/st_geometry

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Set the `st_geometry` property to `NULL`.

```
library(sf)
nc <-  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
class(nc)
## [1] "sf"         "data.frame"
st_geometry(nc) <- NULL
class(nc)
## [1] "data.frame"
```

Also (though this won't remove the `attr(nc, "sf_column"`):

```
nc <-  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
as.data.frame(nc)
```

Comment: I had tried `nc$geometry <- NULL` before, but your suggestion did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: is there a piped version of this? `sf %>% mutate(geometry = NULL)` doesn't work

Comment: Maybe it's called "geom" and not "geometry"? (It's never going to be constant). Another way is ` x %>% st_set_geometry(NULL)`.   Either of these might be in dev, not CRAN though I'm not checking carefully where I'm at locally.

Comment: @mdsumner makes a great, indirect, point. Somebody has to actually write the method, it does not happen by magic. Since sf is a new object class in R many methods may not be available or not behave as expected.

Comment: Is there a method that works for POINT or MULTIPOINT sf objects? When I try to do this with either of those I end up with a n × 0 df.

Comment: recommend to use `st_set_geometry(sf, NULL)` or `sfheaders::sf_to_df(sf, keep = TRUE)` if you want the coords as well (`keep` refers to the data though, but same effect ultimately)

Comment: This retains the geometry column but drops the actual geometry `as.data.frame(x)` and, since the geometry column is always the last one, you can drop the attribute column using `as.data.frame(x)[,-ncol(x)]` This would allow for using it in a pipe version of code.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans: The geometry column is not always the last one. Case in point: `read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) %>% mutate(lastcol = 1)`.

Answer (score 84):

To drop the geometry column, use [`st_drop_geometry()`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_geometry.html):

```r
library(sf)
nc <-  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc_df2 <- nc %>% st_drop_geometry()
class(nc_df2)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

Before `st_drop_geometry()` was added to the **sf** package (in [November, 2018](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/commit/c7a156f213820a09093657dcbc0046d33e579fdb)), one could produce the same result using the `st_set_geometry()` function, like this:

```r
library(sf)
nc <-  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
class(nc)
#> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"

nc_df <- nc %>% st_set_geometry(NULL)
class(nc_df)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1):

why not simply select the columns that you would like?

```
as.data.frame(sf[,"some column name"])[,1]
```

Comment: This extracts a single column as a vector (`sf$\`some column name\`` is equivalent and simpler), and does not answer the question.

Comment: well, you can index as much columns with this method as you like, so I do not really see why this should not solve the problem. In addition is it easier than the method suggested above.

Comment: 1. The problem was to extract the entire data.frame, not selected columns. This solution is not particularly well suited for this purpose, except for very small datasets, and certainly is not "sf-native". 

2. I guess the simplicity of a method might be a matter of opinion, but `st_set_geometry`, `st_drop_geometry` and `st_geometry` are all mostly self-explanatory, and shorter than your method.

Answer (score 1):

`as.data.frame(your_sf_object)[,-ncol(your_sf_object)]` returns all the attribute columns except for its geometry. Also, use `as.data.frame(your_sf_object)[,-8]` if your 8th column is geometry.

If you prefer to use data.table rather than data.frame, you can use

`data.table(your_sf_object)[,-ncol(your_sf_object),with=F]`

or `data.table(your_sf_object)[,-8,with=F]` if your 8th column is geometry.

NOTE: This is my answer to an already old question, but time will come when I need this solution again but I forgot how I did it, so this is a good place to store the solution. Anyway, I got this solution from this thread. Sincerely, Yours Truly...

Comment: You know what, however the other answers might be better in their own special way, this subsetting method is what I needed to be able to export to … a widely used table calculation software, without creating another R object I need to think about `rm()`-ing.